# How to treat a meta-repository of git repositories?

Tags: git

Given a tree of git repositories in a project directory, e.g.

```
Projects/
+A/
|+.git/
+B/
|+.git
```

I'd like to set up a git repository `Projects.git` that does not track the project's contents but only their existence and status. Someone cloning this repository should only have a sekeleton of uncloned repositories `A`, `B` etc. and individually activate whether they are kept in sync or not. A typical workflow would look like this:

- First time setup: `git clone server:Projects.git`
- Activate project `A`, which also clones it
- Now every `git-push/pull`, independently of whether it's in `Projects/` or `Projects/A` should update both `A.git` *and* `Projects.git`'s information about `A`. Anything related to `B` should be ignored since it's inactive and locally empty
- Activate project `B`, cloning that as well
- Now any `git-push/pull` in `Projects` should also do so in both `A` and `B`, while a push/pull in `A` should not influence `B`
- Deactivate project `A`, which (after verifying `A.git` doesn't need a `git-push`) empties the local directory `A`, with no influence on `Project.git`

How can this be treated best? My current approach would be some hook-magic, but I'm not familiar enough with [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) to see whether this could be achieved with submodules or whether I need to use some other solution.

Answer (score 7):

The 'meta' tool is fantastic for this.

You can find it on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/meta

You can use it to clone a meta-repo and all sub-repos at once which is great.

You then use it to apply operations to all your sub-repos, eg to pull your meta-repo and all sub-repos:

```
cd my-repo
meta git pull
```

There's an article here with help to get started and use 'meta':
https://medium.com/@patrickleet/mono-repo-or-multi-repo-why-choose-one-when-you-can-have-both-e9c77bd0c668

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed what [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) are for:
Tracking the exact configuration (ie the exact commit SHA1) of each subrepos.

As detailed in "[How do I git clone --recursive and checkout master on all submodules in a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474847/how-do-i-git-clone-recursive-and-checkout-master-on-all-submodules-in-a-single)", you can clone your parent repo and all its submodules in one command.

As explained in "[True nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)", you can modify them provided you realize that each one is in a [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714) mode (you need to checkout a local branch first), and that you need to commit and push in the submodule first, before going back to the parent repo, commit and push there (to record the new configuration, ie the new submodules SHA1)

You can remove a submodule directory without damaging the parent repo references to that submodule.

---

[The OP Tobias Kienzler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321973/tobias-kienzler) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779197/how-to-treat-a-meta-repository-of-git-repositories/12779920#comment17276742_12779920):

It sounds kind of what I want, but the detached head is rather useless in this case - when I clone a submodule, it should be at it's master head.
Basically I'm looking for a way to have a local index of all projects available without having to clone them individually, and a "sync all projects that are currently cloned" all-in-one command.

I [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779197/how-to-treat-a-meta-repository-of-git-repositories/12779920#comment17277767_12779920) having a look at [**git-slave**](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/):

> Gitslave creates a group of related repositories—a superproject repository and a number of slave repositories—all of which are concurrently developed on and on which all git operations should normally operate;
>   so when you branch, each repository in the project is branched in turn.
>   Similarly when you commit, push, pull, merge, tag, checkout, status, log, etc; each git command will run on the superproject and all slave repositories in turn.

Comment: It sounds _kind of_ what I want, but the datached head is rather useless in this case - when I clone a submodule, it should be at it's master head. Basically I'm looking for a way to have a local index of all projects available without having to clone them individually, and a "sync all projects that are currently cloned" all-in-one command. Maybe using a git repository for this is actually a bad idea?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler then you can have a look at git-slave, which is closer to what you are looking for: http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

why not use what git already provides:

> git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive]

```
git submodule foreach git checkout develop
git submodule foreach git commit
git submodule foreach git push
```

Comment: The simple answer to this response is to point to the many different articles about submodules; for example 

    https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/

there are many more.  Many developers have found git submodules confusing and in may cases they seem to be the wrong solution.  There are definitely some situations where they seem to work right.  For this to be a good answer a clear answer where they would work and how to avoid the pitfalls would be needed.