# Error debugging and build in Git PowerShell command and Import in Android Studio 1.1.0

Tags: android, git, powershell

I want to use Indic-Keyboard github project for build an application. So when I clone it to my repository and try to build I get build failed with an exception that

```
Cannot evaluate module ime : Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

I create my own release key for key store in android studio 1.1.0 according to developer.android.com's suggestion for Signing Your Own App

and store it in E:\GitHubCloneProject\AddSubmoduleAndroidStudio\CloneProject\java\keystores\android.jks.

and also set ANDROID_HOME=E:\Android Sdk in my system environment variable by using the
  following suggestion from stackoverflow.

I follow the procedure for initialize,update and add submodule according to github project "austimkelly/my-android-project/How-to-Use".

When I try to import in my android studio I get the error

```
Can not invoke method readLine() on null Object.
```

I'm using gradle 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

checkout your indic-keyboard/ime folder, if it is empty follow these steps-

1. after using this command "git clone --recursive git@github.com:smc/Indic-Keyboard.git" use cd indic-keyboard to navigate to project directory
2. use "git checkout -f HEAD" to check the status
3. use "git submodule update --init --recursive" or "git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout master" as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474847/how-do-i-git-clone-recursive-and-checkout-master-on-all-submodules-in-a-single/6475033#6475033) stackoverflow question.
4. then go to build.gradle in your clonned directory/indic-keyboard/java and remove signingConfigs and buildTypes part from it, after saving import java folder to android studio and hopefully everything will work

   - @CSE09 are you able to use it in your app, if so please guide me how you did that, as I am struggling to convert it into a library project in android studio