# Git: Recursively switching branch (checkout) on all submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-alias

I'm working on a git repo that contains `submodules`. I've got branches by the same name (like `master`, `development`..) in all submodules (including parent module) and they all track their corresponding remote branches.

I'd like to have same branches checked-out in all submodules at a time. In other words, what I want is that if I switch to `development` branch in parent module, all submodules should also switch to `development` branch so that my working tree remains consistent with branches.

Manually doing this is painful and repetitive. Is there is shortcut?

Comment: `git submodule update` would update them (to detached HEAD) anyway. How are you going to utilize the current branches?

Comment: **@max630** you are right. Its just that in my team we don't *normally* use `git submodule update`. Rather we do `git pull --rebase origin master --recurse-submodules`, so that each `submodule` gets `rebase`d with `master` (irrespective of which `branch` is currently *checked-out* in `submodule`s). I acknowledge that this serves my *isolated use-case* and may not be required by majority of people

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `--recurse-submodule` flag. E.g.: `git checkout master --recurse-submodules`

> Using --recurse-submodules will update the content of all initialized submodules according to the commit recorded in the superproject. [https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---no-recurse-submodules]

Comment: you can also `pull` like this, i wonder what else is possible??
`git pull --recurse-submodules`

Comment: According to git-checkout, this will leave submodules in a detached HEAD state. It states "Just like git-submodule[1], this will detach HEAD of the submodule."

Answer (score 4):

I achieved this with the help of `git-alias` and a `bash script`.

Following is my bash script called git-rcheckout.sh taken from [@qbein's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474847/how-do-i-git-clone-recursive-and-checkout-master-on-all-submodules-in-a-single/6475033)

```
#!/bin/bash
((!$#)) && echo No branch name, command ignored! && exit 1
git checkout $1 && git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout $1
```

Next I aliased this script to rcheckout command as [told by @u0b34a0f6ae](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309430/how-to-embed-bash-script-directly-inside-a-git-alias)

```
git config --global alias.rcheckout '!sh ~/path/to/script/git-rcheckout.sh'
```

---

ISSUE:
Currently it works only when you do `git rcheckout branch-name` from parent module. You can probably update the bash script to do it from submodules also, but I'm too lazy. So suggestions are welcomed.